# assign value to field in Java class instance object

Tags: java, class, object

I am iterating through packages finding classes and instantiating them however I want to be able to assign values to their public fields, how do I do this please?

**Please note as I am iterating through packages I do not know what I will find so I do not want to have to cast the object the class in the code to access the fields, so can I do something like obj.getDeclaredFields()? and use this somehow?**

```
public class Test {
    public String a;
    public int b;
}

Class myClass = Class.forName("Test");
Object obj = myClass.getInstance(); //This is what I have so far
obj.a = "test";
obj.b = 1;      // I need something like this


Test t = (Test)obj; // I dont want to have to do this as the next step
```

Thanks!

Comment: `myClass.getDeclaredFields()`?

Comment: You can also use a BeanHelper, it will allow you to iterate methods and [properties](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#describe%28java.lang.Object%29) and set/get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
try {
    myClass.getDeclaredField("a").set(obj, "test");
    myClass.getDeclaredField("b").setInt(obj, 1);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    // Whatever needs to be done
}
```